# After delete open the previous message

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

In Office 365, Outlook, I change my preferences on the Mail-Other section to 'After moving or deleting an open item' - to open the **previous** item.  This works fine for the current session.  However, it returns to 'open the **next** item' the next time I get into Outlook.  How do I make this preference persist?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the following registry key to see whether it helps:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\preferences

REG_DWORD: **aftermove**

Value data: **2**